# Good approach to cache the image between NSFileManager and NSCache in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to know what is the best option for saving the images in Cache. Actually I was trying to follow the process which is described 
[Here](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/13315-image-caching-tutorial.html).

In this he is using NSFileManager to cache the image. But somewhere I saw the NSCache class. I am not sure about NSCache as I never used this. I just want to save many images (Cache) may be 100 or more than that by taking multiple pictures at the same time from camera. And when I done by taking images then I will copy all the images to camera roll.

What should I use for this approach? Right now I am using NSFileManager.

Comment: I don't think, you need `Cache` for your requirement. Normally we use Cache where Network activity is involved to reduce the data usage. You are doing all locally, no need of Cache.

Comment: Since `NSCache` is store in memory and on the device its file system I would go with the `NSFileManager` option. Because you state you will have  a 100 or more images you memory is not big enough to store all these.

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks for your suggestions :) Ok until I don't remove the images from FileManager, the images will be still there.. Right?

Comment: The images you store the device file system use, for example, `NSFileManager ` will be there until you remove them of the app is removed. But only if you store them in the document directory, if you use the cache directory (has no relation to `NSCache`) they might be removed if the system is running out of storage.

Comment: @rckoenes Ok now I understood completely. It was a very nice explanation for me. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to rely on hard working of other fellow developers - use third party lib. My best suggest is [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).  It's making miracles with caching and reusing images, easy to integrate and use.